# When does 'the closure of open balls is the same as close balls' imply length space?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, metric-spaces

That's basically it, easy to state question.

Suppose $(X,d)$ is a metric space space where the closure of open balls is the same as close balls. 
What conditions can we set on $(X,d)$ so this implies that it is a length space.

Any references?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Good question. I don't know the answer but did you search in the book *Metric spaces of non-positive curvature* by Bridson and Haefliger?

Comment: You should define what you mean precisely by length space. I think with an appropriately broad definition (say, one that would include ${\bf Q}$ with the standard metric), they could be equivalent. With the simplest definition, it would seem you would at the minimum need to require something like locally path connected.

Comment: Questions like "what condition do I need to ensure that ..." are somehow weird. A correct (but useless) answer to your question is "$(X,d)$ is already a length space". Do you have any conjecture on what condition could be good for you?

Comment: @Crostul Now that I look back, I was thinking of really weak conditions. I realized that being a length space is an extremely more restrictive condition. sorry for taking so long to answer and thanks for the help.